# Ember Component not recognized - bind-attr bleeds to controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm working on implementing a rangeslider as an Ember component. For the most part it has been working quite well. The problem came when I tried to add some handlebars magic. In particular I want to bind the style attribute left to a value in the component. The handlebars is shown below.

```
<div class="slider-connector" {{bind-attr style=leftPercentage}}>
    <div class="handle-container handle-container-lower">
        <div class="handle">

        </div>
        <div class="handle-label">
            <strong>Value:</strong>
            <span>10.00</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JS is

```
App.SingleSliderComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
template: 'components/single-slider',
classNames: ['ember-slider'],
left: -5,
right: 5,
rangeStart: -10,
rangeEnd: 10,
leftPercentage: 'left: 0%;',
rightPercentage: 'left: 100%;',
init: function() {

},
didInsertElement: function() {

},
setLeftPercentage: function() {
    var val = (this.get('left') - this.get('rangeStart'))/(this.get('rangeEnd') - this.get('rangeStart'))*100;
    this.set('leftPercentage', 'left: ' + val + '%;');
},
setRightPercentage: function() {
    var val = (this.get('right') - this.get('rangeStart'))/(this.get('rangeEnd') - this.get('rangeStart'))*100;
    this.set('rightPercentage', 'left: ' + val + '%;');
},
});
```

The component is implemented via

```
{{single-slider}}
```

The problem is that it isn't taking leftPercentage and rightPercentage from the Component, but rather the Controller that the component exists in. As I understand it, components should be completely separated from the controller. Looking at the Ember-Inspector, it doesn't show the single-slider component when I select 'show components', which leads me to believe it is having problems detecting the component, which would explain why the binding is not localized to the component.

My component is in templates/components/single-slider.hbs and my js is in components/singleSlider.js (but that shouldn't matter since everything is concatenated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! Clearly I wasn't careful enough when implementing my component - the solution is to call

```
this._super();
```

in the init call.